# sql add id column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, addition

Hi I have a table with

```
name
a
b
c
d
```

need to add a id column starting from mid number and want in sql

```
name    ID
a        10262
b        10623
c        10624
d        10625
```

Comment: what do you mean "mid number" ?  What have you tried ? Are you getting an error? what's the error ? What RDMS is this in? Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: sql server, I just want to add another column which is ID column which has number starting from 10626 and its a primary key

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to add an auto-incrementing Primary Key ID column if there's already data in the table without copying the data, dropping the table and recreating it.  However, if there's no data you can just add those columns through SQL's Table Editor.  Right click any table in SQL Server and click on "Design"; that will get you to the Table Editor.  When you declare any Primary Key you can set it's "seed" value, which is the number that it will initially start with; in your case, your seed would be 10262, based on your original post.

Comment: You can also do this with a direct SQL statement (something like `ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN myID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(10626, 1)` - do some research on the "ALTER TABLE" command in SQL) but, if you have access to the Table Editor, it's an easier way to manage your Tables (in my opinion)

Comment: how do I add seed value??

Comment: It's the first value in IDENTITY.  In my comment I have `IDENTITY(10626, 1)`.  This will make the column increment automatically for every record inserted.  It will start at my first parameter, 10626, and will increment by 1 for every new record.

Comment: Ooops, I commented about the statement method.  If you're using the Table Editor, when you click a Column it shows a list of Column Properties.  There's a group called Identity Specification; you can set that to Yes and it has 2 properties underneath it for Identity Increment and Identity Seed.